# Validate Search Criteria : Java

Tags: java, validation

I have to implement search based on almost 12 different fields.
For validation and processing, I am facing a lot of challenges. Following are those with which I am seeking inputs/help.

```
Classes:
SearchCriteria
(has) UserCriteria and AddressCriteria
```

PS. A few fields are related to user e.g. First Name, Date of Birth etc. which goes in UserCriteria and a Few fields are related to address e.g. Street Name, Building Number etc. which will go into AddressCriteria

Based on these criteria I have to search users.

- Validate that at least one parameter is not null/not empty. I do not
  want to keep checking each and every field for null and emptiness.
- Before search validate based on which criteria you need to initiate
  search. e.g. User or Address?
- Implement validations such a way that you need not to worry about
  specific field validation before adding it in query criteria

**EDIT:**

NOTE : I need to prepare a message with all the valid fields which will be passed to the module which helps me finding all records, I am not dealing with DB directly.

Answer (score 0):

What if both of your objects (UserCriteria and AddressCriteria) has a method like,

```
public ArrayList<String> getSearchableFields() {

    //return a ArrayList of searchable fields
}
```

Then you'll be able to call getSearchableFields() on each method and see what fields are available to use for your search.

Comment: hey, as far as I think that can be a horrible option. just imagine what do you need to do in case you want to implement the same

Comment: What I was thinking to then build a SQL string with the values from the method return value EG. WHERE name = 'xxx' and age = 'yyy'... That's of course if you were using SQL... It's just a thought, I haven't tried to implement it

Comment: ohh, that way would still work, but I just need to prepare a message and send it to other module which will help me getting details, let me update question to avoid confusions.

Comment: Can you still not use the ArrayList to build your message, the same way you'd build a SQL statement?

Comment: No, I have to populate key and values, I can use the list in case I only need to populate keys e.g. user name

Comment: What if you get getSearchableFields() to return a HashMap with keys and values?